# scatter function in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
from numpy import array
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fileread import file2matrix
datingDataMat,datingLabels = file2matrix('iris_data.txt')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(datingDataMat[:,1], datingDataMat[:,2],15.0*array(datingLabels), 15.0*array(datingLabels))
plt.show()
```

This code is displaying error as::

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

According to the author i should be able to generate different colors based on datalabels.

Comment: can you post a few lines of your iris_data.txt? so we know what is in your datafile?

Comment: 40920 8.326976 0.953952 largeDoses
14488 7.153469 1.673904 smallDoses
26052 1.441871 0.805124 didntLike
75136 13.147394 0.428964 didntLike
38344 1.669788 0.134296 didntLike
72993 10.141740 1.032955 didntLike
35948 6.830792 1.213192 largeDoses
42666 13.276369 0.543880 largeDoses
67497 8.631577 0.749278 didntLike
35483 12.273169 1.508053 largeDoses
50242 3.723498 0.831917 didntLike
63275 8.385879 1.669485 didntLike
5569 4.875435 0.728658 smallDoses

Answer (score 3):

The array should contains numeric values.

```
>>> 15.0 * array([1,2])
array([ 15.,  30.])
```

---

```
>>> 15.0 * array(['1','2'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Check the value of `datingLabels`.

Comment: datinglabels contains strings only.Strange how the author has shown it is working

Comment: @PavanRavishankar, Try `ax.scatter(datingDataMat[:,1], datingDataMat[:,2])`.

Comment: @tcp : do one thing, convert all datingLabels inside iris.txt to 0, 1, 2. e.g for didntLike save 0 , for smallDoses save 1 likewise, then it will work

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar problem. Here is what I did . I converted the label to contain numeric values.I am working on python 2.7 , not sure if 3.3 version would have handled it automatically.

newdatLabel = []

for item in datLabel:

```
if item == 'largeDoses':

    newdatLabel.append(2)

elif item == 'smallDoses':

    newdatLabel.append(1)

elif item == 'didntLike':

    newdatLabel.append(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach

Author provides datingTestSet2.txt

You can download it here (I assume you've done it already)

http://www.manning.com/pharrington/

you can find forth column's values are numeric in this file

but still datingLabels is filled with string values like ['3', '2', '1', .....]

so 15.0*array(datingLabels) doesn't work

**To convert the type of an array, use the .astype() method**

like **15.0*array(datingLabels).astype(float)**

```
from numpy import array 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fileread import file2matrix
datingDataMat,datingLabels = file2matrix('datingDataTest2.txt')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(datingDataMat[:,1], datingDataMat[:,2],15.0*array(datingLabels).astype(float), 15.0*array(datingLabels).astype(float))
plt.show()
```

it should work!

Comment: thanx @J.U. , I think there is one more problem with the kNN.py at line 36, it was trying to convert a string type into int .. so I removed int() conversion then it worked pretty fine ,, well datingDataTest2.txt is correct isn't it??